# How to avoid repetitive codes in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```js
verifyModuleTitles(expectedTitles) {
        cy.get('h3[class*="block-module_title"]')
            .should('have.length', 3)
            .then((items) => {
                cy.log(items[0])
                expect(items[0]).to.contains.text(expectedTitles[0])
                expect(items[1]).to.contains.text(expectedTitles[1])
                expect(items[2]).to.contains.text(expectedTitles[2])
            })
    }
```

I've written a common function `verifyModuleTitles` that can be invoked as below

```js
verifyModuleTitles(['xx', 'yy', 'zz'])
```

Now everything works great, except i find that it's repetitive and i wish to improve to something as below, but its not working

```js
verifyModuleTitles(expectedTitles) {
        cy.get('h3[class*="block-module_title"]')
            .should('have.length', expectedTitles.length)
            .then((items) => {
                items.forEach((x, index) => {
                    expect(x).to.contains.text(expectedTitles[index])
                })
            })
    }
```

The exception thrown seems like looping is not being supported in cypress?

**UPDATES**

[image]

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Also where is `items` being defined? Should this be `expectedTitles.length`?

Comment: Both `blockTitles` & `items.length` are `undefined`, I mean `blockTitles` is never used.

Comment: @BrandonBoone: i've added the screenshot

Comment: @BrandonBoone: made a typo in terms of `.length` but the exception is thrown at `items.forEach`, `items` is an array consist of 3 dom elements

Comment: try [...items].forEach

Comment: @KeithNicholas: It works! Exactly what i needed . Could you please write a new answer with a lil explanation on why an additional array spreading + initialization needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items are the children which is not exactly an array, its an HTMLCollection (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

so you can do

```
[...items].forEach()
```

which then turns the collection into an array